# Reading only x number of bytes from file in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, hex, byte

I use this code to read full hex of file :

```
Dim bytes As Byte() = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
Dim hex As String() = Array.ConvertAll(bytes, Function(b) b.ToString("X2"))
```

Can i only read like first X number of bytes and convert it to hex?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a ton of ways of getting bytes from a file in .NET. One way is:

```
Dim arraySizeMinusOne = 5
Dim buffer() As Byte = New Byte(arraySizeMinusOne) {}
Using fs As New FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None)
    fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
End Using
```

The `arraySizeMinusOne` is the max index of your array - so setting to 5 means you'll get 6 bytes (indices 0 through 5).

This is a popular way of reading through a large file, one chunk at a time. Usually you'll set your buffer at a reasonable size, like 1024 or 4096, then read that many bytes, do something with them (like writing to a different stream), then move on to the next bytes. It's similar to what you would do with `StreamReader` when dealing with a text file.

Comment: EnosI get 'Buffer' is a type and cannot be used as an expression error.

Comment: You must have imported a namespace where that word is a class name. Just change `buffer` to something else, like `theBuffer`.

Comment: If you hit F2 with the cursor on `FileSteam` all sorts of info on how to use it comes up.  `fs.seek(filePos, pt as SeekOrigin)` will set the position for fs. filePos would be the position in the file, like FileLength - X bytes,  SeekOrigin would be `System.IO.FileStream.Begin` in this case.  Then read 5 more bytes after you seek to the right location.

Comment: @Plutonix I did not understand fully,but i will try.

Comment: ask a new question if you cant sort it out

Comment: @Plutonix How can i use fs.seek code to register starting point,from where last bytes will be read?I know question is weird,I can't sort it out correctly.

Comment: that is for `last bytes of file` from comment 4...if you want to seek X bytes from where you are now in file, use `fs.seek(XBytes,System.IO.FileStream.Current)`

Comment: @Plutonix It is "scanner".Reads byte from file and converts it to hex,and compares it to database.Executable files have same bytes at first lines,but each is different in last lines/bytes,so that's why I need this.I am not visually editing any file.

Answer (score 1):

In a more advanced case with offset support I have found this code in an open source DLL file.

```
Function readX(ByVal file As String, ByVal offset As UInt64, ByVal count As UInt64) As Byte()
    'hon Code 2023 (FUNCT v1.1.00)
    Dim buffer() As Byte = New Byte(count - 1) {}
    Using fs As New FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)
        fs.Seek(offset, SeekOrigin.Begin)
        fs.Read(buffer, 0, count)
    End Using
    Return buffer
End Function
```

A basic usage is

```
readX(file, offset, count)
```

E.g.

```
readX("test.txt", 2, 2)
```

It reads from the 2nd to 4th byte of the test.txt file.