# Read 6 bytes from .iso file

Tags: arrays, vb.net, hex

I've searched around but cannot find the solution. This [Reading only x number of bytes from file in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19013640/reading-only-x-number-of-bytes-from-file-in-vb-net) seems to point me in the right direction but I can't get it to give me the HEX info I need...

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If (OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
        TextBox1.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim filename = TextBox1.Text
    Dim arraySize = 5
    Dim buffer() As Byte = New Byte(arraySize) {}
    Using fs As New System.IO.FileStream(filename, IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read, IO.FileShare.None)
        fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
    End Using
'this solves it!
 Dim hextottext As String = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer)
    MsgBox(hextottext)

End Sub
```

Thats the code I'm using - when stepping through it,

```
fs = System.IO.Filestream
```

and I have no idea why.

Basically I want to read the first 6 bytes, convert them to readable text from hex, this is for an .iso image file.

Thanks for the tip on the chr function, but I found this during my searches!

Comment: This does what you want, the first 6 bytes are in the `buffer` variable, what do you want to do with them?

Comment: Is there a reason that you're wanting to convert from hex? This code produces decimal output and from there it's simply a case of using the**chr** function to produce the character for that decimal number - **chr(65)** produces "**A**"

Comment: i want to translate the hex to readable text

Comment: But the code reads integers from the file