# Exclude first 'x' bytes of binary data from a file while reading in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, binary-data

I am a noob working on binary files. And its an extension to this question: [Reading 'x' bytes of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19013640/reading-only-x-number-of-bytes-from-file-in-vb-net#)

My binary file size if *1025 KB*, which is *1049600 bytes* that contains *1024 bytes* of header info. I would like to read remaining data only after **1023th** bit, which equals *1048576 bytes*.

How do I exclude the first *1024 bytes*?

I am using the same code but I can't get it to work, is there anything wrong in my code?

```
Dim arraySizeMinusOne = 5
Dim buffer() As Byte = New Byte(arraySizeMinusOne) {}
Using fs As New FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None)
    fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
    Dim _arraySizeMinusOne = 1048575
    Dim _buffer() As Byte = New Byte(_arraySizeMinusOne) {}
    'Process 1048576 bytes of data here
End Using
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `byte` array of length the entire file minus, the size you exclude, and minus 1. The last `1` is because vb arrays are different from c# ones. In vb:

```
Dim buff() As Byte = New Byte(10) {}
```

creates a 11 size array and in c#:

```
byte[] buff = new byte[10];
```

creates a 10 size!

```
Using fs As New FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None)
    Dim buff() As Byte = New Byte(CInt(fs.Length - 1024 - 1)) {}
    Dim buffTotal() As Byte = New Byte(CInt(fs.Length - 1)) {}
    'read all file
    fs.Read(buffTotal, 0, buffTotal.Length)
    If fs.Length > 1024 Then
        'move from 1024 byte to the end to buff array
        Buffer.BlockCopy(buffTotal, 1024, buff, 0, buffTotal.Length - 1024)
    End If
End Using
```

`buffer` is not a good name because in vb exist already a class `Buffer`! Change it to something else like `buff`.

Comment: Thanks but its showing: **Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection.** exception

Comment: @Thomas Oooops! My wrong. I thought the offset was from the stream but it was from the array. Fixed. See edited one.

Comment: @Thomas If you open the correct file then *1,049,600 bytes* is `buffTotal` and *1048576* is `buff`. Check what `fs.Read` returns. It should return *1,049,600 bytes*

Comment: Yes it was my mistake!

Comment: The FileStream is seekable. Just set its Position property to the offset  and read the remaining bytes.  Then there is no need for the Buffer.BlockCopy and the associated overhead.