# How can I read a specific byte in a byte array in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, file, binaryfiles

I have a binary file being loaded into a Byte array using `Dim settingsBinary As Byte() = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllBytes(settingsFile)` where settingsFile is the path to my binary file.

Let's say that my binary file has got three bytes and I want to read the first byte as a Boolean (00 = False, 01 = True). How can I get those bytes? I have tried to use [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19013640/reading-only-x-number-of-bytes-from-file-in-vb-net) to read those three bytes, but I can't wrap my head around it.

Just to clarify, I need to get the three bytes separately: Get the first byte, then set `CheckBox1.Checked` to the first byte, and so on with the other bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A byte array works just like any other array: You can use an *indexer* to access a specific element.

```
Dim firstByte As Byte = settingsBinary(0)
Dim secondByte As Byte = settingsBinary(1)
Dim thirdByte As Byte = settingsBinary(2)
```

And then you can convert the byte into a boolean:

```
Dim firstBoolean As Boolean
Select Case firstByte
    Case 0
        firstBoolean = False
    Case 1
        firstBoolean = True
    Case Else
        Throw New Exception("Invalid first byte in settings file: " & firstByte)
End Select
```

(Generalizing the conversion logic into a method that can be used for all three bytes is left as an exercise to the reader.)

Comment: Thank you! It worked flawlessly. The only thing I had to change was `Case 1` to `Case 255` because the value was being stored as binary (True, False = 255, 0)